# Adding Input to Logged in User Interface Customize Look

Tags: input-formats

With Drupal 7, can I add the ability for the logged in user to update and save a few form fields that then populate a list below the form? They could then edit / delete entries?

Is there a module that creates custom interfaces, or is this something I would be doing in the template?

[image]

Comment: did you try using the [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module ?

Comment: @Jayaram Hey that might just work. I'll dive into it here.